# Simpler, portable way to iterate over all char values?

Tags: c++, char

For a class I'm teaching I needed to write a piece of code to iterate over all possible `char` values. I wanted to do this in a way that was portable across different C++ implementations. This meant that

- I can't assume `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`,
- I can't assume `char` is eight bits,
- I can't assume that `sizeof(int) > 1`,
- I can't assume the `int32_t` etc. types exist,
- I can't assume that integer overflow will not trap,
- etc.

The best solution I came up with was the following unusual `do ... while` loop:

```
char ch = numeric_limits<char>::min();
process(ch);
do {
    ch++;
    process(ch);
} while (ch != numeric_limits<char>::max());
```

This approach works, but it feels pretty clunky to me. It intuitively makes sense that an approach like this might be needed because the number of increments is one more than the number of possible characters, but perhaps there's a fundamentally different approach available that more closely resembles a traditional `for` loop.

Is there a portable way to achieve this that's less clunky than this?

Comment: If this is for a class, do you really need to be so pedantic as to not assume that `sizeof(int) > 1`? Relaxing that restriction would make it a simple task. Iterating with `int ch` would be short, sweet, and plenty portable, *in practice*. I'm not convinced there's pedagogical value in being so zealously standards compliant -- unless you're teaching an advanced C++ course, that is.

Comment: @JohnKugelman You're absolutely right that this is total overkill - I certainly could get away with assuming `sizeof(int) > 1` because I know which compiler chains my students are using. But I'm still curious because this doesn't seem like it would be too hard and yet it required a bit more finesse than I expected.

Comment: Indeed, looping is so much easier when you can go one past the end.

Comment: Is C++20 an [option](https://godbolt.org/z/n53cn16o7)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but perhaps there's a fundamentally different approach available that more closely resembles a traditional for loop.

Well, you *can* use an actual `for` loop:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

void process(char ch)
{
  std::cout << static_cast<long>(ch) << ' ';
}

int main()
{
  for ( char ch = std::numeric_limits<char>::min(); ; ++ch )
  {
    process(ch);
    if ( ch == std::numeric_limits<char>::max() )
      break;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper class that looks like a container.

```
struct Chars {

    enum {
        Chars_MIN = std::numeric_limits<char>::min(),
        Chars_MAX = std::numeric_limits<char>::max()
    };

    struct Iterator {
        char c_;
        bool end_;

        Iterator (char c, bool e = false) : c_(c), end_(e) {}

        auto & operator ++ () {
            if (c_ == Chars_MAX) end_ = true;
            else ++c_;
            return *this;
        }

        auto operator * () const { return c_; }

        auto operator == (const Iterator &other) const {
            return c_ == other.c_ && end_ == other.end_;
        }

        auto operator != (const Iterator &other) const {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
    };

    Iterator begin () const { return Iterator(Chars_MIN); }
    Iterator end () const { return Iterator(Chars_MAX, true); }
};
```

Then, you can use the modern `for` syntax:

```
    Chars ccc;
    for (auto x : ccc) {
        process(x);
    }
```